# Is it possible to get a collection (array or object) from a SQL query containing a set of filters?

Tags: mysql

I'm used to other technos, I want to retrieve some info from a database, so to give the context:
I have a **"plaformname"** column which is the name of each platform, a **"populationname"** column (each platform is divided in populations) and finally I have a **"nb_of_actions_completed_by_users"** that contains a count.

My table looks something like (excluding the index column):

| plaformname | populationname | nb_of_actions_completed_by_users |
| --- | --- | --- |
| platform1 | populationA | 8 |
| platform1 | populationB | 0 |
| platform2 | popX | 0 |
| platform2 | popY | 5 |
| platform2 | popZ | 5 |

I would like to retrieve the **"nb_of_actions_completed_by_users"** grouped as something like (***not picky*** if it is on arrays, objects, mix, etc, I'm fine with any structure, also I don't care about including or not the ones with zero values):

```
[{
  "plaformname": "platform1",
  "populations": [{
    "populationA": 8, //this is the nb of actions
    }
  }]
},
{
  "plaformname": "platform2",
  "populations": [
    { 
      "popY": 5
    },
    {
      "popZ": 5
    }]
}]
```

-or- (or any other structure that matches the grouping idea)

```
{
  "platform1": {
    "populationA": 8 //this is the nb of actions
  },
  "platform2": {
    "popY": 5,
    "popZ": 5
  }
}
```

Or do I have to run an individual query for each platform? Thanks in advance for the help/observations.

***MYSQL version*** 5.7.X (X<30)

Comment: Do you really need "0" values?  That is tricky to get unless you have a list of "popX, popY, popZ" some where.

Comment: I'll update the question with the information, the version is 5.7.X (X < 30), and @RickJames actually no, I'm ok without the zero values

Comment: This does not seem like a database question, but rather how to covert some information into JSON.  Correct?

Comment: @RickJames I think the OP wants to know if it is possible to obtain all this data in one request, I've never got the need to do so for so many levels, I'd normally just request the db multiple times to avoid complexity